# VSCode - If I want to use StandardJS for Linting, should I uninstall ESLint?

Tags: eslint

I have to use StandardJs for JavaScript linting inside VSCode.
Until now I always used ESLint for JS linting.

Do I need now to remove and uninstall ESlint and ESlint VSCode plugin before I can use StandardJS?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to disable ESlint on your machine, in fact, you could integrate StandardJs with ESlint.

All you need to do is these:

```
npm i -D eslint eslint-config-standard eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-node 
eslint-plugin-promise eslint-plugin-standard
```

Then create an `.eslintrc.json` file and simply extend standard:

```
module.exports = { "extends": "standard" };
```